# When to use dynamodb.client, dynamodb.resource and dynamodb.Table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am working on Dyanamodb using Boto3 and Python. One of the issues I am finding is  when should we use the `dynamodb.client`, `dynamodb.resource` and `dynamodb.Table`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`dynamodb.client` provide a low level access directly to the DynamoDB apis. You can call only the apis listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CurrentAPI.html).

The service `resource` objects like `dynamodb.resource` provides a more object oriented way of access the AWS resources. DynamoDB is a fairly straightforward service in terms of the different kinds of things you create in AWS. (Basically the main object you create are tables, as opposed to a service like EC2 where you have many different kinds of objects (instances, security groups, launch configurations, etc).

The `dynamodb.Table` object provides a simplified way of accessing the data in the table. It will marshall and unmarshall the data automatically from the DynamoDB format to a simpler for you.

Format examples
Using the dynamodb.Client data might look like this

```
{
  "id": {
    "S": "a unique id"
  },
  "date": {
    "N": "12345678901234"
  }
}
```

Whereas using the `Table` resource you will get data that looks like this

```
{
  "id": "a unique id",
  "date": 12345678901234
}
```

I recommend using the `Table` resources since it simplifies data access.

Comment: is one faster than the other?

Comment: They make the same API calls. There will be a little extra overhead for the marshaling/unmarshaling, but before you optimize anything you should measure it.

Comment: Which of these allow built-in exception mapping à la https://stackoverflow.com/a/68699154/1021819 ? Thanks!